# Limits of C++ Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

i've got a issue with `std::vector` class, i created a `struct`

```
struct Triplet{
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
};
```

And i created a `vector<Triplet> T`.
My problem is that it won't contain as many elements as i need, even though `T.max_size() = 357913941` i got only  `T.size() = 60540697` or  `T.size() = 40360465` using that function

```
vector<Triplet> T;
while(true)
{
    Triplet t;
    t.first = 1; t.second = 1 ; t.third = 1;
    try {
        T.push_back(t);
    } catch (...) {
        break;
    }
}

qDebug() << T.size();
```

can anyone explain why is it doing that please ?
i'm running on Windows 10 and 16Go of RAM, with Qt and VSC++ 2017 x86 (due to Lemon library which i couldn't compile for x64),

Comment: You should catch and print your exception to determinate which error occurs that break your while.

Comment: the question is not a good dupe, but this answer fits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813203/4117728 TL;DR: long before you reach `max_size` you will run out of memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ vector max\_size();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813124/c-vector-max-size)

Comment: If your int is 4 byte and padding makes your struct 4 ints, you have around 1G of data. No idea what the memory layout on 32 bit win is, but 1G is possible as max chunk size for malloc.

Comment: Also using `reserve` with planed desired size, can improve speed and practical maximum capacity of a vector.

Comment: "as many elements as i need". How many do you need?

Comment: ***No idea what the memory layout on 32 bit win is, but 1G is possible as max chunk size for malloc*** It used to be that because of memory fragmentation around 1.2GB was the largest single allocation without the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker switch and / or rebasing the dlls. Here is an answer I wrote long ago about this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911298/memory-leak-does-window-have-a-safeguard-to-prevent-max-memory-reached/19911739#19911739](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911298/memory-leak-does-window-have-a-safeguard-to-prevent-max-memory-reached/19911739#19911739)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `std::vector` needs a contiguous (=no holes) chunk of memory to exist in.
Furthermore, when pushing elements to a vector you can overshoot the internal capacity, meaning that it has to allocate memory for another `std::vector` (usually double the size) and copy the elements over.

Keep in mind that in 32-bit Windows programs, you only have 2 GB of available memory space to play with in a single process, regardless of how much memory your system has. Your vector with size 60540697 * 12 is taking up 700+ MB of that. There is simply no place to allocate the next size (1.4GB) because the memory space is too small.

The simplest solution is to compile in 64-bit mode, which has *plenty* of virtual memory. As a stop-gap solution you could try pre-allocating space in the `std::vector` with `T.reserve(80000000)` or so. This will avoid an intermediate copy but probably will not be enough. It might even fail if your memory space is fragmented in a bad way!