# Win32 compiler option and memory allocation

Tags: c++, compatibility

I tried to compile the following code:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "netcdf.h"
}

int main() {
    const int Ntime = 336;
    const int Nlon = 1442;
    const int Nlat = 1021;
    double* dhsum_vals = new double[Ntime * Nlat * Nlon];
}
```

When compiling with the 32-bit version, I get the error C2148   "total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes". I think, the problem here is that a 32-program does not allow to use as much memory as I want here. If I compile with the 64-bit version, I get the error, that netcdf cannot be found as I downloaded the 32-bit version. So, my solution will be to download the 64-bit version of the netcdf library. However, my intention, when taking the 32-bit version, was that it should be more compatible. Is there another solution for my problem than taking the 64-bit version of netcdf?

Comment: `double* dhsum_vals = new double[Ntime * Nlat * Nlon];` That is not on the stack. However if this is a 32 bit program you will be limited to probably around 1.2GB for the largest allocation on windows by default because of the 2GB user space / kernel split and memory fragmentation.

Comment: @drescherjm, you're right, misread, and assumed stack. My mistake.

Comment: The /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker flag can help with this along with dll rebasing however it will be much simpler to just switch to 64 bit. I remember playing this game in the early 2000s but I was glad once we switched all machines to x64 so I did no longer have to deal with this. I mentioned that in this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911739/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911739/487892)

Comment: Error talks about 0x7fffffff = 2,147,483,647 bytes, and you are reserving 336 * 1442 * 1021 * sizeof(double) = 3,957,494,016, assuming a double are 8 bytes in a 32-bit system (you can print sizeof(double)) to be completely sure.

Comment: Without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE `0x7fffffff` was the entire address space for a 32 bit program.

Comment: `3,957,494,016` if this is a requirement you will have to use 64 bit.

Comment: Wow, that's a freaking large array. As a side-note (irrespective of the main issue), since this array is being declared in `main()` and will presumably live for the duration of your program, you'd probably do better to define the array outside of `main()`, and don't use `new`, so that it will be statically allocated. There's no reason to make something use the heap if its lifetime is the life of the program, and its size is constant and known at compile time.

Comment: @phonetagger I just used ```main()``` such that the code is self-sufficient. Actually, in my own code, I do not have it in the main method. I used to ```new``` to allocate the memory dynamically because the stack memory is limited.

Comment: If your array will live for the entire life of the program, the most efficient way of allocating it is to make it statically allocated. I.e. not on the stack, and not dynamically allocated. Do you know how to allocate something statically? Historically, that would often be called a "global variable" (or global array), as opposed to one allocated on the stack, which might be called a "local variable" (or local array).

Comment: @phonetagger No, I don't know how unless you mean by adding ``` static ```.  Could you please elaborate in which sense it would be more efficient?

Comment: There is some amount of overhead ("bookkeeping") associated with using dynamic memory (`malloc()`, `new`). For a huge array, the percentage of the wasted overhead is tiny, but since you don't need it to be dynamic (do you?), you might as well just make it statically allocated, assuming you won't need multiple copies of it (e.g. one per class instance, if you're programming with C++ classes). Assuming you'll only have one such array in your whole program, you can just declare it outside of any function, and it becomes "global".

Comment: If you want it to be a member of a C++ class, and if you'll only need one such array regardless of the number of class instances you'll make, then you can declare it `static` and then there will only be one such array in the whole program, used by all instances of that class. If (going back to the previous "global array") you add the `static` keyword in front of the definition, then the array will still be statically allocated ("global"), but it will only be known inside that translation unit (C++ file). Note that the terms "static" and "statically allocated" are only loosly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Microsoft Windows, the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a 32-bit process is limited to 2^32 bytes, which is about 4 GB. However, the higher 2 GB are reserved by the system, so that you effectively only have about 2 GB of address space.

Also, this address space is fragmented, so you will not be able to allocate 2 GB in one consecutive chunk. You may be able to get up to 2 GB if you try several smaller memory allocations.

Although it is possible for a 32-bit process to use more than 4 GB of memory using the [Address Windowing Extensions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/address-windowing-extensions), this requires special security privileges and makes your code unnecessarily complex, as you cannot have all the memory you are using mapped into your virtual address space at once. Therefore, I strongly suggest that you compile a 64-bit version of your application instead, when you are handling large amounts of memory.

I don't think that using 64-bit will make your program any less compatible, as nearly all modern hardware and operating systems support it.

Comment: I remember investigating AWE about 15 years ago. Too much effort and complexity added for what I needed.